# How to merge the flatMap emits?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic2, rxjs

After switchMap operator I used the flatMap operator to getting the object observable data

```
return this.db.list(`UserPlaces/${this.authData.auth.auth.currentUser.uid}`, {
    query: {
      orderByChild: 'deleted',
      equalTo: false
    }
  })
  .map((locations: any) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(locations,null,2)); // this log is called 0
    return locations.map(location => {
      return location.$key;
    });
  }).switchMap(ids => {
    return ids.map(id => {
      console.log(id) // this log is called 1
      return this.db.object(`Devices/${id}`)
    });
  }).flatMap((x: any) => {
    console.log(x); // this log is called 2
    return x;
  }).map((x:any)=>{
    console.log(x); 
     if(!x.deleted){
      return x;
    }
  })
  .do(console.log) // and this log is called 3
```

Log 0:

```
[
  {
    "deleted": false,
    "guest": false,
    "owner": true
  },
  {
    "deleted": false,
    "guest": false,
    "owner": true
  },
  {
    "deleted": false,
    "guest": false,
    "owner": true
  },
  {
    "deleted": false,
    "guest": false,
    "owner": true
  },
  {
    "deleted": false,
    "guest": false,
    "owner": true
  },
  {
    "deleted": false,
    "guest": false,
    "owner": true
  },
  {
    "deleted": false,
    "guest": false,
    "owner": true
  }
]
```

log 1:

```
-L8CmrV8BBQCVv_0x_-6
-L8CnDqHz_VWP9dpw-tz
-L8CxQ_bz4EQSPa4STUd
-L8CxSaF1JdHwhn3YyrC
-L8WVlwWj-ghpZsx2PEE
-L8WW5QbxxNMeWonNdSg
-L8XJHI0-ZhPAA9Xy3Sx
```

log 2:

```
FirebaseObjectObservable {_isScalar: false, $ref: U, source: FirebaseObjectObservable, operator: ObserveOnOperator}
FirebaseObjectObservable {_isScalar: false, $ref: U, source: FirebaseObjectObservable, operator: ObserveOnOperator}
FirebaseObjectObservable {_isScalar: false, $ref: U, source: FirebaseObjectObservable, operator: ObserveOnOperator}
FirebaseObjectObservable {_isScalar: false, $ref: U, source: FirebaseObjectObservable, operator: ObserveOnOperator}
FirebaseObjectObservable {_isScalar: false, $ref: U, source: FirebaseObjectObservable, operator: ObserveOnOperator}
FirebaseObjectObservable {_isScalar: false, $ref: U, source: FirebaseObjectObservable, operator: ObserveOnOperator}
FirebaseObjectObservable {_isScalar: false, $ref: U, source: FirebaseObjectObservable, operator: ObserveOnOperator}
```

log 3:

```
{deleted: false, id: "", name: "new place", owner: "cS81XkHhVHNv0nmpVit0Glpuc1t1", tone: "default", …}
{deleted: false, id: "", name: "new one", owner: "cS81XkHhVHNv0nmpVit0Glpuc1t1", tone: "default", …}
{deleted: false, id: "", name: "nice", owner: "cS81XkHhVHNv0nmpVit0Glpuc1t1", tone: "default", …}
{deleted: false, id: "", name: "new one", owner: "cS81XkHhVHNv0nmpVit0Glpuc1t1", rooms: {…}, …}
{deleted: false, id: "", name: "das", owner: "cS81XkHhVHNv0nmpVit0Glpuc1t1", tone: "default", …}
```

What i need is merging the log 3 to be an array of objects and not separated Objects.

My target for that is :

showing an ion-select that looping through the array and shows the place name.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `toArray()` at the end of you chain if the source completes. If it doesn't you can collect results with `scan()`

Comment: @martin thank you for your replying but can u add your opinion as a question please,, it more clear

Comment: You want something like [zip](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) ?

Comment: @sabithpocker i'm new one in RXJS world so i don't know what zip exactly doing,, so can u add a answer  to test the zip operator ? And i will read about it in meantime

Comment: Please be patient. Read it and reply here.

Comment: I tried the .zip not worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the source completes:

```
return this.db.list(`UserPlaces/${this.authData.auth.auth.currentUser.uid}`, { ... })
  ...
  .toArray()
  .do(console.log) // and this log is called 3
```

or if it doesn't collect results with `scan()`:

```
return this.db.list(`UserPlaces/${this.authData.auth.auth.currentUser.uid}`, { ... })
  ...
  .scan((acc, item) => [...acc, item], [])
  .do(console.log) // and this log is called 3
```

Btw, it looks like you're purposely unwrapping the array anyway with:

```
...
.flatMap((x: any) => {
  console.log(x); // this log is called 2
  return x;
}
...
```

Comment: .scan((acc, item) => [...acc, item], []) can u explain about this please and how to use it

Comment: It just collect items as they arrive and emits the resulting array

Comment: This is the right idea but I think you want reduce instead of scan

Comment: @AluanHaddad can u add an answer please

Comment: it efficient to add `.scan((acc, item) => [...acc, item], [])`  @martin

Comment: @KhaledRamadan this question doesn't really need another answer. This answer is fine it's just a little bit off.

Comment: ` .scan((acc,items)=>{
        return [acc,items]
      },[])` and that doesn't work  that y i'm asking

Comment: actually i got nested arrays !  @AluanHaddad

Comment: @KhaledRamadan You're using it wrong. Why you just don't copy what I posted?

Comment: because i don't understand what you mean in the `...` before the acc,, plus i used your method and i got nested array,,btw sorry i about my stupid question but I'm new in the programming overall

Comment: One more question please,, how to wait the observables to finish before publish the last array

Comment: because im getting the array sequential way [{}] [{},{}] ... I don't need this